# How do I create a Local html file to open webpage and inject a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have a legacy web application that we are not allowed to modify yet.  We need to add a new function to the application in the short term.  We have been told that we may modify the webpage with any local scripts we want but we have to wait 4 months before they will unlock the application.

So my goal is to create a webpage locally, click on that local html file and have it open the url for the legacy application, and then inject the new JavaScript function to the application.

Comment: "...not allowed to modify...need to add a new function" those two don't match. What do you mean by "modify the webpage with local scripts"?

Comment: what is wrong with going to the application, right clicking, save as... html file. Then edit that local html file with your scripts and open it in a browser?

Comment: It sounds like they're referencing using something like TamperMonkey or a bookmarklet.

Comment: The application does not work unless you start it by calling the application startup JavaScript on the internally hosted URL.  (Not allowed to Modify was qualified as Not allowed to modify today.)

Comment: If your boss gives you unclear instructions, you should ask him/her for  clarification rather than bringing an ambiguous question to SO.

Comment: It is a department issue.  My group has the go ahead, but our changes will not be added to production for at least 6 months.  I was asked to find a way to get it done today while we wait.

Answer (score 0):

On "your" page, use an iFrame to "import" the page you cannot edit, on your page add whatever modifications you need/want.

If there is no server side scripting on the page, then copy the page source to your page, and add whatever you want to it.  It is difficult to give you a focused answer without having access to or more information about the actual legacy page.

Comment: The application does not load or work when in an iframe.  I just verified this again.

Comment: What is the URL of the page your are trying to modify?

Comment: you can not get to it, it is internal only.

Comment: there are many reasons why an iframe does not work, some are fixable, and others not.  If the original application is blocking the use of its pages, perhaps the server admin will remove that block from the page in question.  If not, there are a lot a things that could be tried to make the page display in the iframe.  One of them might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done directly since browsers prevent cross site scripting so injecting js from local machine will complain with same origin errors the only workaround i know is to use developer tools and open console then you can type your JavaScript there and run it directly